# How to iterate over an objects's field retrieved from database using php, and modify the field?

Tags: php

I have a table, which contains dreams (long texts). I want to display them on my site, but before that, I want to make some transformation. If the dream contains a certain word, I want to wrap a `span` around it. I am getting back all the entries from the database:

```
public function getDreams() {
    $dreams = Dream::all();
    $this->highlightWords($dreams);
    return view('home')->with('dreams', $dreams);
}

public function highlightWords($dreams) {
    $wrap_before = '<span class="highlight_match">';
    $wrap_after  = '</span>';
    $key_words = 'example';
    foreach ($dreams as $value) {
        preg_replace("/($key_words)/i", "$wrap_before$1$wrap_after", $value);
    }
    return $dreams;
}
```

The `highlightWords` function should take the dreams, iterate over them, and then return the variable with the wrapped around words. I think the problem is, that the dreams are not coming from the database as a string, but in a JSON structure:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "dream":"I had the dream of...",
  "created_at":null,
  "updated_at":null
},
{
  "id":2,
  "dream":"Another dream with some text",
  "created_at":null,
  "updated_at":null
}
```

How can I modify the `dream` values, and wrap them around with a `span` ?

EDIT

HTML:

```
@if(count($dreams) > 0)
    @foreach($dreams as $dream)
        <p class="dream-id">DREAM {{sprintf("%03d", $dream->id)}}</p>
        <p class="dream-body">{{$dream->dream}}</p>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: use `json_decode($dreams, true)` to convert into loop and then iterate over the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code, I've added comments to the code. But the `json_decode()` may be an important part of getting started...

```
// Test data - note this has a [ at the start and a ] at the end which isn't in your data
$dreams = '[{
  "id":1,
  "dream":"I had the dream of...",
  "created_at":null,
  "updated_at":null
},
{
  "id":2,
  "dream":"Another dream with some text",
  "created_at":null,
  "updated_at":null
}]';

// I've extracted this to be standalone for testing, you need to put public back for a class method
function highlightWords($dreams) {
    $wrap_before = '<span class="highlight_match">';
    $wrap_after  = '</span>';
    // Changed the next word to something in the text
    $key_words = 'dream';

    $dreams = json_decode($dreams);

    foreach ($dreams as $value) {
        // $value is each record, using $value->dream will update the dream text
        // As preg_replace returns the string with the replacements - assign this value back
        $value->dream = preg_replace("/($key_words)/i", 
               "$wrap_before$1$wrap_after", $value->dream);
    }
    return $dreams;
}

print_r( highlightWords($dreams));
```

which gives (formatted) ...

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [dream] => I had the <span class="highlight_match">dream</span> of...
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [dream] => Another <span class="highlight_match">dream</span> with some text
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: It all seems working fine, but now my HTML file is not working -> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object. I added the HTML to the question. I tought that json_encode should return an Object this way. Can you take a look?

Comment: I've updated the code - the `json_decode()` has the second param removed and the code around the `preg_replace()`.  I've also removed the `json_encode()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Use [`json_decode($dreams, true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert the JSON format string to associative array, so that you can iterate over it. Note that second parameter has to be set to `true`, in order to get array (otherwise it returns a `stdClass` object).
- While iterating over the array, you need to access the array key as well, in order to be able to modify the array.
- Use `json_encode()` function to convert it back to JSON format string, and return it.

Try:

```
public function highlightWords($dreams) {
    $wrap_before = '<span class="highlight_match">';
    $wrap_after  = '</span>';
    $key_words = 'example';

    // Convert JSON string to array
    $dreams = json_decode($dreams, true);

    // Iterate over the array and do your operations
    foreach ($dreams as $key => $value) {
        $dreams[$key]['dream'] = preg_replace("/($key_words)/i", "$wrap_before$1$wrap_after", $value['dream']);
    }

    // convert the array back to json format and return
    return json_encode($dreams);
}
```